# Understanding the output of electric fence and gdb

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb, electric-fence

When debugging a program that terminates with a segfault, electric fence, in conjunction with gdb, returns this:

`"ElectricFence Exiting: mprotect() failed: Cannot allocate memory
[Thread 0xb0bd4b70 (LWP 5363) exited]
Program exited with code 0377.`

I actually thought electric fence would be more helpful. What does this mean? How can I interpret this piece of information?   There doesn't seem to be any stack left that I can look at, or at least `bt` won't return anything.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Also, when I debug the program, it doesn't look like it's consuming all the memory... there's still  ~1GB left, that is half of it. So I shouldn't even be concerned with swap space, right?

Answer (score 17):

You have probably run out of memory map areas. The default is known to be low when using debug allocators.  This can be adjusted at runtime via

```
echo 128000 > /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count
```

or by adding this line to /etc/sysctl.conf and rebooting:

```
vm.max_map_count = 128000
```

The max_map_count number defaults to 65530 and can be increased as high as MAX_INT if necessary.

For more information see:

- [max_map_count](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_max_map_count.html)
- [Side effects when increasing vm.max_map_count](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7000830)

Answer (score 3):

The output of ElectricFence simply means that *it* ran out of memory and can't help you.

ElectricFence imposes *extremely* high memory overhead, especially for programs with lots of small heap allocations.

If you are on Linux, try Valgrind instead.

Also note, that your first step for a program that dies with `SIGSEGV` should *not* be running it with ElectricFence; rather you should run the program under debugger and see *where* it crashes.

Comment: Hmm... I have still a lot of memory available when it returns that message. Could it be just about to use it all at once? That's strange.

Comment: So, anyway, when exactly should I use electric fence, if not in this case?